# How can I create Classroom Share Button like link text?

Tags: share, google-classroom

I need to create share button as text(share on google classroom), not Icon. 
I read docs https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton but found info only about Icon.
It's possible to create text link to share Classroom?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe you take [the tour first](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also check [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, only buttons are supported at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! Just create a link and set the it's `href` to:

```
https://classroom.google.com/u/0/share?url=URL_GOES_HERE&title=TITLE_GOES_HERE
```